# Inverting Horizon?

Tags: optics, vision, perception

everyone knows that looking at the horizon at something going far away, the last thing you see from it is its top, but what if you had a ground going up very very very slightly and something moves away from you, will you see its top at last or its bottom at last? use this diagram to simplify it: [image]

Comment: Could you clarify what would hide the top of the object at the horizon in the 2nd case?